# NTAuthority\iusr in Sharepoint

Tags: user

After pulling out page requests reports in SharePoint 2013, we could find few entries for the username NTAuthority\iusr.

If NTAuthority\iusr refers to anonymous user , all the users in domain have access to the site. How could it be possible?

Thank You